# Manipulation a private value of child view without accessing it directly

Tags: swift, swiftui

I was looking a light approach to manipulation of a private value in child view without accessing that value directly or involving me with notification or ObservableObject, I came a cross to this approach, I am okay with the result, but I need to know any improvement or better approach.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var reset: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            CircleView(reset: reset)
            
            Button("reset") { reset.toggle() }
            
        }
    }
}



struct CircleView: View {
    let reset: Bool
    @State private var size: CGFloat = 100.0
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: size, height: size)
            .onTapGesture { size += 50.0 }
            .onChange(of: reset, perform: { _ in size = 100.0 })

    }
}
```

---

Update:

```
struct CircleView: View {
    @Binding var reset: Bool
    @State private var size: CGFloat = 100.0
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: size, height: size)
            .onTapGesture { size += 50.0 }
            .onChange(of: reset, perform: { newValue in
                
                if (newValue) { size = 100.0; reset.toggle() }
                
            })
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `@Binding` for `reset`  this is a terrible approach this recreates the `View` completely (init gets called again)and while this is a small view in a `View` that is more involved it would be a waste of resources. I suggest you watch Demystify SwiftUI from WWDC21

Comment: @loremipsum: thanks, I forgot to add to my question that the parent view does not interested to keep tracking the value of size via binding or a model or what ever with other thing, the only interest is just reseting it. The parent can keep tracking the value directly via Binding no big deal, but the goal was just reseting it.

Comment: for the `reset` not the `size`.

Comment: @loremipsum: I used your advice and updated my code, how it looks like now?

Comment: That looks fine to me. It is a standard SwiftUI setup.